# Emacs - Predictive mode

Tags: emacs

I am trying to setup the Predictive Mode of Emacs and to use it with the LaTeX-mode. I have one problem: as soon as LaTeX-mode is loaded, it loads "auto-overlays" and it takes up to two minutes before I can begin to work, which is very annoying. I believe that this "auto-overlays" is used to switch between dictionaries according to where I am in the LaTeX document.

Here is the part of my .emacs that concerns the predictive mode:

```lisp
(require 'predictive)
(autoload 'predictive-mode "predictive" "predictive" t)
(set-default 'predictive-auto-add-to-dict t)
(setq predictive-main-dict 'dict-english
      predictive-auto-learn t
      predictive-add-to-dict-ask nil
      predictive-use-auto-learn-cache nil
      predictive-which-dict t)
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'predictive-mode)
(setq completion-use-hotkeys nil)
(setq predictive-ignore-initial-caps t)
(custom-set-variables
   '(auto-completion-syntax-alist (quote (accept . word))))
```

Do you have a solution?

Comment: have you downloaded it yourself or used it as a package? It can really pay of to compile the `.el` file in to binaries. It will speed up your loading time!

Comment: I have both the `.el` and `.elc` files in my load-path. Which one of them is used?

Comment: Turns out that the Predictive Mode creates a `.predictive` folder where you have your .tex file and stores some info in it. I deleted this folder and it works fine now. Any ideas about the purpose of this folder?

Comment: I have no idea of the predictive folder (I don't use it myself). On the other matter, that is good, `.elc` is the binary file of the equivalent `.el` file.